# How to upgrade Nuget Package Manager on WebMatrix 2

Tags: webmatrix-2

I was trying to install a package on WebMatrix but got an error that says I must upgrade my Nuget Package Manager, and the message gave me a link to visit. However the link does not work, and I failed after trying many times to upgrade the Nuget Package Manager. How do I simply upgrade Nuget Package Manager on WebMatrix 2?

Comment: I have the same problem. Gives me the link, I visit it, download and install Nuget again, try again, and it says the same thing. Because of this I can't get the OAuth Helper, and thus can't let clients sign in with their Google account.